# Type mismatch Runtime error 13

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim a As String
    Dim h As Double
    Dim d As Double
    Dim r As Double

    a = ComboBox1.value
    r = TextBox2.value
    d = TextBox3.value
    h = TextBox4.value
End Sub
```

Is there any problem in the above code which i have written in userform_initialize ....... I am getting an error type mismatch I am sure that there is no problem with rest of my code

Earlier i had defined variables a,h,d,r in commandbutton1_click , Now i had just moved them to userform_initialize and I am getting this type mismatch error

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

The type mismatch means that whatever `foo.Value` evaluates to cannot be coerced to a `Double`. (Perhaps it's a blank string).

One workaround would be to write code of the form

```
a = 0 'The default value
On Error Resume Next 'Switch off error handling
a = ComboBox1.Value
On Error Goto 0 'The idiomatic way of switching error handling back on.
```

Or handle the potential error more gracefully. (Using `Len` perhaps?).

Comment: `IsNumeric` would also be a possibility (to detect invalid entries).

Comment: It stands in for ComboBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3, or TextBox4. Us geeks use foo as a *metasyntactic variable*.

Comment: Okk Thanks...........And what difference does defining the variables a,h,d,r in another sub commandbutton1_click and defining the variables in sub userform_initialize make to it ?

Comment: I can send my complete code to you personally (by gmail or something else) I dont know if i can send personal mails through stackoverflow ?